# update asp.net text box

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, textbox

I have problem with updating data.

Sample:

```
protected void GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   GridViewRow row = GridView1.SelectedRow;
   string id = row.Cells[1].Text;
   Response.Redirect("edit.aspx?id="+id);                    
}
```

after this code transition to another page with update cmd.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  DataView dv = (DataView)SqlDataSource1.Select(DataSourceSelectArguments.Empty);
  foreach (DataRowView drv in dv)
  {
    IDLBL.Text = drv["ID"].ToString();
    Name.Text = drv["Name"].ToString();
    SName.Text = drv["SecondName"].ToString();
    Ocenka.Text = drv["Graduate"].ToString();
    Klass.Text = drv["Class"].ToString();
  }
}

protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ARM_TSPConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
  con.Open();
  string upd = "UPDATE Info SET Name=@Name, SecondName=@SecondName, Graduate=@Graduate, Class=@Class WHERE ID=@ID";
  SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(upd, con);
  cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", IDLBL.Text);
  cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SecondName", SName.Text);
  cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Graduate", Ocenka.SelectedValue);
  cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Class", Klass.SelectedValue);
  cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", Name.Text);
  cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
  Response.Redirect("main.aspx");
}
```

I clicked button, and was redirected  to main page. But nothing else, update doesn't work. :(
where do I have a problem?

Comment: Are you sure you are specifying that `@ID` value correctly? Try debugging to see what the value really is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was found.Just add in Page_Load if(!isPostBack)

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   if (!IsPostBack)
   { 
        DataView dv = (DataView)SqlDataSource1.Select(DataSourceSelectArguments.Empty);

        foreach (DataRowView drv in dv)
        {
            IDLBL.Text = drv["ID"].ToString();
            Name.Text = drv["Name"].ToString();
            SName.Text = drv["SecondName"].ToString();
            Ocenka.Text = drv["Graduate"].ToString();
            Klass.Text = drv["Class"].ToString();
        }

    }
```

Now, all working good.

Answer (score 0):

Your update sql query looks fine:

```
con.Open();
com.ExecuteNonQuery();
con.Close();
```

that is try using this function instead and debug it to see if there is a sql exception thrown.

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
      SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ARM_TSPConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
      string upd = "UPDATE Info SET Name=@Name, SecondName=@SecondName, Graduate=@Graduate, Class=@Class WHERE ID=@ID";
      SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(upd, con);
      cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", IDLBL.Text);
      cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SecondName", SName.Text);
      cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Graduate", Ocenka.SelectedValue);
      cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Class", Klass.SelectedValue);
      cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", Name.Text);
      con.Open();
      com.ExecuteNonQuery();
      con.Close();
      Response.Redirect("main.aspx");
    }
    catch (SqlException e)
    {

    }
}
```

**UPDATE:** Think I've realised why it's not working for you... you have a column called class... but class in sql server is a reserved keyword... so you must put square brackets around it ... like so

**Edited the escaping (made a mistake as pointed out by Hans in the comment below)**

```
    string upd = "UPDATE Info SET Name=@Name, SecondName=@SecondName, Graduate=@Graduate, [Class]=@Class WHERE ID=@ID";
```

Comment: Wouldn't you need to escape like: `[Class]=@Class`? But the OP would get errors if that was the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really know where is the problem, but for sure you need to refactor your update statement using the IDisposable capabilities of the connection object, it shoul look like this:

```
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(
           ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ARM_TSPConnectionString"].ConnectionString))
{
    string upd = "UPDATE Info SET Name=@Name, SecondName=@SecondName, Graduate=@Graduate, Class=@Class WHERE ID=@ID";
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(upd, connection);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", IDLBL.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SecondName", SName.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Graduate", Ocenka.SelectedValue);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Class", Klass.SelectedValue);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", Name.Text);
    cmd.Connection.Open();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```